# craftcms/vue-asset Related Error on Craft and Plugin Update

Tags: craft3, plugin-imageoptimize

When updating my plugins or craft I get the following error...

```
Error: The "https://composer.craftcms.com/p/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize-imgix/c642ab1cfc1bf5e4c9c3c265837b1e5201a6ed55436f1bbb47558a9c63a49384.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Composer output: Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
```

Doing a google on craftcms/vue-asset - it looks like it is depreciated - so I'm not sure why I would need it.

Comment: I am getting this error anyone out there to help. I am upgrading Craft CMS to 3.7. <warning>Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
<warning>Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1 - The requested package laravel/homestead could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name. Problem 2 - The requested package laravel/homeste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed by P&T:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5063

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/issues/171

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/issues/169

Comment: Thanks, Andrew!